# Magento Multistore

Tags: magento, multistore

I have created two store on single magento installation and its working fine
 1. www.example.com (use this as a wholesale only logged in customer can see price)
 2. www.example.com/retail (Use this for retail any one can see price)

But im getting error on login | create an account 
If i click login in or create an account in www.example.com/retail it never goes to www.example.com/retail/account it goes to www.example.com/account this is my error
How do i create separate log in for two store
Can any one help

Comment: Can you give the errors?

Comment: in example.com/retail we have login | create an account right if we click login or create an account on example.com/reatil it goes to example.com/login page but it goes to example.com/retail/login page